# How should a Gnome applet store its configuration data?

Tags: python, applet, gnome

I have a Gnome applet written in Python. In order to save configuration data/settings, it creates a file `~/.appname`.

However, this prevents multiple instances of the applet from being added to the panel because each cannot have its own settings.

How can I store the settings in a way that allows each instance to have its own unique settings?

**Update:** I specifically want to know how to store settings *per instance*.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The recommend way for an applet would be to use [GConf to store preferences](http://people.gnome.org/~tvachon/doc/tutorial.html#gconf) and to use one key per instance so that you can store individual settings. From [Panel Applet GConf Utilities](http://library.gnome.org/devel/panel-applet/stable/panel-applet-Panel-Applet-GConf-Utilities.html):

> Applets typically define a set of
>   preferences using a schemas file and
>   panel_applet_add_preferences(). Such
>   preferences apply only to an
>   individual applet instance. For
>   example, you may add two clock applets
>   to the panel and configure them
>   differently.
>
> In order for the preferences to only
>   apply to a single applet, each applet
>   must have a seperate GConf key for
>   each of these preferences. The methods
>   described below provide convient
>   wrappers around the usual GConfClient
>   functions and operate on these
>   per-applet keys.

Comment: **Perfect!** Just what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Python example with the applet:

```
import gconf
client = gconf.client_get_default()
gconf_root_key = applet.get_preferences_key()

client.set_string( gconf_root_key + "/myvar", "foobar")
myvar = client.get_string( gconf_root_key + "/myvar")
```