# How do I make a Gnome Panel applet (written in python) store seperate settings for each instance?

Tags: python, gnome

Someone [asked this question about a year ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3018287/how-should-a-gnome-applet-store-its-configuration-data) but I was unable to turn either of the answers into usable code. The accepted answer seemed to reference a C function (I could find no python equivalent) and the other one referenced a python function that did not work for me (applet.get_preferences_key() returns None). wat do? Examples would be awesome...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't access the pages linked in the accepted answer from the other question for some reason. However, you can access the GConf C libraries through PyGObject introspection:
`from gi.repository import GConf`. So, the function that they recommend (if only I could load the web page to see), is presumably available in Python. Note that if your applet is using pygtk at all, there might be conflicts with using PyGObject introspection (though I think if you're using introspection only for GConf and not for GTK, you should be OK).

Here are the contents of GConf via introspection:

```
['ChangeSet',
 'ChangeSetForeachFunc',
 'Client',
 'ClientClass',
 'ClientErrorHandlerFunc',
 'ClientErrorHandlingMode',
 'ClientNotifyFunc',
 'ClientPreloadType',
 'Entry',
 'EnumStringPair',
 'Error',
 'ListenersForeach',
 'ListenersPredicate',
 'UnsetFlags',
 'Value',
 'ValueType',
 '__class__',
 '__delattr__',
 '__dict__',
 '__dir__',
 '__doc__',
 '__file__',
 '__format__',
 '__getattr__',
 '__getattribute__',
 '__hash__',
 '__init__',
 '__loader__',
 '__module__',
 '__name__',
 '__new__',
 '__path__',
 '__reduce__',
 '__reduce_ex__',
 '__repr__',
 '__setattr__',
 '__sizeof__',
 '__str__',
 '__subclasshook__',
 '__weakref__',
 '_introspection_module',
 '_load',
 '_namespace',
 '_overrides_module',
 '_version',
 'concat_dir_and_key',
 'debug_shutdown',
 'enum_to_string',
 'error_quark',
 'escape_key',
 'init',
 'is_initialized',
 'key_is_below',
 'postinit',
 'preinit',
 'string_to_enum',
 'unescape_key',
 'unique_key',
 'valid_key',
 'value_decode']
```